# Received email stating waiting for approval, you will receive offer letter in next few business days?

Tags: job-offer, new-job

I applied for Spring co-op in January, at the time of interview on Tuesday (interview was quite good so I am hopeful), HR said, tomorrow you will hear a decision from us since they are going to be real quick in taking decision regarding this co-op as work needs to be started in February anyhow.

However, I did not get any response so I dropped a follow-up email on Friday. Then, after 5 days, on Wednesday I received an email from HR, they are offering me the job, after approvals are done, they will send me offer letter in next few business days.

Today, its Tuesday (already 6 days) and I have not received offer letter yet, should I send a follow-up email again as they never pick the call. Would it seem like I am getting desperate? since it is a co-op for Spring Semester and semester has already begun, should I really wait for receiving an offer letter even now or should I forget about all this and move on with some other on-campus jobs?

Update: I thought of waiting for 1 more week and did not send any email or call them.
Finally, today, I received the call from HR and received offer letter. I have my joining within next 2 weeks.

Thanks everyone for helping me out.

Comment: I would write again, specially because they say need to start in February, and that is tomorrow. But next time when someone tell you `"few days"`, you should ask for a more specific range. A few days isnt the same for an ant than to an elephant ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems they have a poor human resource management. Anyway, there's nothing wrong with a follow-up email because they seem not to entertain those people who are not also interested with the job. Don't worry, you do not sound desperate. You only want a proper and on-time response from them (which is professional).

Possible reasons why they don't get back to applicants [on-time]:

1. They have a poor human resource management (which may also reflect the quality of the entire organization).
2. They do not entertain those people who are not also interested with the job.
3. Applicants are too many to accommodate (they are understaffed).

While waiting, there's nothing wrong if you look for other jobs. Just tell the others that you have an ongoing job application. Every one understands that.